# C++/CLI 2 dimensional array allocation fails

Tags: c++-cli

The code below prints 0 and 3. Is this a code-generation bug?
I am running this under .NET 4.0 with Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 RC

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    unsigned long long d1 = 5, d2 = 3;
    auto arr = gcnew array<Object^, 2>(d1, d2);
    Console::WriteLine(arr->GetLength(0));
    Console::WriteLine(arr->GetLength(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Update:
I have filed a connect bug report at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788830/c-cli-2-dimensional-array-allocation-with-unsigned-long-long-size-argument-generates-invalid-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that definitely quacks like a bug.  The compiler generates bad IL for this code, it appears fatally confused about having to convert the `unsigned long long` to an int.  You can see the bad IL by running ildasm.exe, the relevant snippet is:

```
  IL_000a:  ldloc.3
  IL_000b:  conv.i4
  IL_000c:  ldloc.2
  IL_000d:  conv.i4
  IL_000e:  conv.i8             // <=== here!
  IL_000f:  newobj     instance void object[0...,0...]::.ctor(int32,
                                                              int32)
```

The instruction at address IL_000e is the trouble maker, converting the int produced by IL_000d back to an 8-bit integer.  This then fumbles the arguments passed to the array constructor.  Oddly, the IL verifier doesn't catch it either.

It is not an Update 3 bug, this fails in VS2008 as well in the exact same way so this is certainly an old issue.  It is also highly specific for a forced conversion from unsigned long long to System::Int32, it doesn't go wrong for a long long.  The probable reason this has gone undetected for so long.  Do note that the compiler emits a warning for this code, complaining that it has to truncate the unsigned long long to an int.  So catch this mishap by compiling with /WX turned on.

The workaround for both the bug and the warning is to explicitly cast the variable yourself:

```
auto arr = gcnew array<Object^, 2>((int)d1, (int)d2);
```

You can submit this issue at connect.microsoft.com.  Let me know if you don't want to take the time to do this and I'll take care of it.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I will submit it on connect.

Comment: @K.M. When you do so, consider adding a link to it here. That way, people who come across this question can also visit and vote up the bug report.

Comment: Just fyi, the IL verifier did not catch it because it was (partially) disabled as C++/CLI generates unverifiable code (unless built with /clr:safe I think). It can not in general know whether the stack is meaningful at the point of the call once the restrictions on verifiable code are lifted.